# How do i assign and obtain values to objects created in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Currently learning Java as a hobby and am making small game projects to reinforce the concepts. So for this one, I've made a method that creates an array of objects, in this case, a "Computer" object. I'm doing this because I want the user to decide at startup how many computer opponents they want to play against, instead of hard coding a set number of them. Now I want to assign and retrieve a value for each Computer object. For example a Computer name, bet amount, and a dice roll guess.

```
public class Computer {
    static int bet;
    static int guess;
    int cash;
    static Computer[] c;

    public static void create(int numComps) {

        c = new Computer[numComps];

        for (int i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {
            c[i] = new Computer();
            c[i].cash = Game.startCash;
            c[i].bet = bet();
            c[i].guess = guess();
            c[i].display();
        }
    }

    public static int bet() {
        bet = Rng.rand(Game.startCash / 50) * 50;
        return bet;

    }

    public static int guess() {
        guess = Dice.roll();
        return guess;

    }

    public void display() {
        String name = "Computer ";
        System.out.println("My name is " + name + " i bet " + bet + " and guess " + guess);
    }
}
```

When i do Computer.create(5) i get

```
My name is Computer  i bet 150 and guess 9
My name is Computer  i bet 50 and guess 3
My name is Computer  i bet 450 and guess 11
My name is Computer  i bet 250 and guess 11
My name is Computer  i bet 50 and guess 10
```

This output gives the appearance of working but i don't think i'm on the right track. For the name i want the syntax to be something like, name = "Computer " + c[i]. Resulting in "Computer 1", "Computer 2", "Computer 3" etc, not sure how to do that correctly. And an individual bet and guess to be assigned to each individual object. Right now i think its just displaying a random number rather than assigning that value to the particular object.

Comment: Why not give your Computer class a `String name;` field, one that you can assign on creation, and then print in the display method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bet` and `guess` member variables shouldn't be static.

To display the id you can add a new `int` member variable, set it to `i` for each computer when you initialize them in the loop, and update the `display()` method to print it.

```
public class Computer {
    int id;
    int bet;
    int guess;
    int cash;
    static Computer[] c;

    public static void create(int numComps) {
        c = new Computer[numComps];

        for (int i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {
            c[i] = new Computer();
            c[i].id = i;
            c[i].cash = Game.startCash;
            c[i].bet = bet();
            c[i].guess = guess();
            c[i].display();
        }
    }

    public static int bet() {
        return Rng.rand(Game.startCash / 50) * 50;
    }

    public static int guess() {
        return Dice.roll();
    }

    public void display() {
        String name = "Computer ";
        System.out.println("My name is " + name + id + " bet " + bet + " and guess " + guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: When i remove the static modifiers i get                                                         
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method bet() from the type Computer
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method guess() from the type Computer

 at Computer.create(Computer.java:16)
 at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: Ok that works, but what if i wanted to access info on for example, "Computer 3" and display it somewhere else in the program?

Comment: Access it as `Computer.c[2].bet` though it would be better to add a method to fetch the value of `bet` and make `bet` private.

Comment: Ok so in my Main class with my main method im doing                
Computer.create(5);
System.out.println(Computer.c2.bet); and i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 c2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: It's `Computer.c[2].bet`, not `Computer.c2.bet`.

Comment: This will do that: `System.out.println(Computer.c[2].bet);`